# Can I search Google+ Photos by location?

Tags: google-plus-photos

I use Google+ auto-backup photos in my smartphone, so there are tons of geotagged photos in my Google+ Photos.

Is it possible to search photos by location?
(From desktop webbrowser or smartphone, doesn't matter.)

Or better yet, have a map view with thumbnails of photos dotting the map. I think this is a great feature that iPhones had from long ago, that is still missing in Android phones, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

When I search [my photos](https://plus.google.com/photos/) with a location (e.g., [Washington, DC](https://plus.google.com/photos/search/washington%2C%20dc)) I only seem to get photos that are geo-tagged for that location, as well as some where the system seems to "guess" the location based on some other criteria. It's not 100% accurate, but it's pretty close, and I'll bet as I use "add location" in the photo's details, it'll get better at showing the appropriate photos by location.

No option for showing them on a map, though. At least, not without some third-party tool.